# Isometry group with non-abelian $\pi_0$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

From work of Saerens--Zame we know that every compact Lie group is the full isometry group of some closed Riemannian manifold. Is there a reasonably explicit example of a metric whose isometry group has a non-abelian $\pi_0$? It would be even better if somebody has an example with $\pi_0(Isom(g))\approx S_3$.

Edit: what about an example of a closed connected Riemannian manifold whose isometry group $G$ is a positive-dimensional Lie group with $\pi_0(G)\approx S_3$ and $G\not\approx H \times S_3$ for any Lie group $H$?

Comment: Well, an equilateral triangle has isometry group $S_3$. It is not a Riemannian manifold, but I guess that with a small perturbation you can "round the corners" and get a manifold with the same isometry group (the metric is the one induced by the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, of course).

Comment: One way to get $S_3$ as a subgroup of the isometry group is to pick a metric on a manifold with a faithful $S_3$-action, for instance $S^2$, and average it with respect to this action. If the metric is sufficiently generic, there should not be any more isometries, so that $S_3$ is the isometry group.

Comment: For $S_3$, how about the isometry group of three points?

Comment: @ArunDebray, yes it works. Now more interested in positive-dimensional examples

Comment: I guess you want not only positive-dimensional, but connected examples.

Comment: The symmetric space of $SO(8)(\mathbf{C})$ has an isometry group whose $\pi_0$ is $S_3$.

Comment: @YCor if it satisfies all requirements, you could post that as an answer

Comment: @YCor:  Actually, $\mathrm{SO}(8,\mathbb{C})$ does not, itself, support triality, which, I think, is what you are going for.  However, the quotient group $\mathrm{SO}(8,\mathbb{C})/\{\pm I_8\}$ (i.e., dividing out by the center of the group) does produce a group that has triality automorphisms.  In fact, as Cartan showed, you can also achieve this with the compact group $U=\mathrm{SO}(8)/\{\pm I_8\}$.  A better example, though would be the universal cover $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant I said the symmetric space of $SO(8)(\mathbf{C})$, not $SO(8)(\mathbf{C})$ itself.

Comment: @YCor:  I'm not sure what you mean by 'the symmetric space of $\mathrm{SO}(8)(\mathbb{C})$'; after all, $\mathrm{SO}(8)(\mathbb{C})$ is, itself, a symmetric space, and its isometry group has two components, not six.  Are you referring to some notion of a symmetric space cannonically associated to a (complex?) semi-simple Lie group other than the Lie group itself?  If so, I apologize, but I'm not aware of such a notion.

Comment: @YCor:  Oh, never mind.  I think I know what you mean:  the *Riemannian* symmetric space $\mathrm{SO}(8,\mathbb{C})/\mathrm{SO}(8)$.  I guess this is the non-compact dual of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes: for every semisimple (without compact factor) real Lie group $G$, I mean $X(G)$ is $G$ modulo a maximal compact subgroup; we have $X(G)=X(G/Z)$ for $Z$ the center. If $G$ is simple, the invariant Riemannian metric of $X(G)$ is unique up to positive scalar multiplication, and in particular the isometry group depends not depend on the choice.

Comment: I guess a simpler example, of much lower dimension than $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$, could be made as follows:  Let $(S^2,g)$ be a metric of positive curvature on the $2$-sphere whose isometry group is a copy of $S^1$ (these are easy to produce), and let $X = S^2\times S^2\times S^2$ endowed with the product metric.  Then the isometry group $G$ of $X$ fits into the following non-split exact sequence: $$ 1\longrightarrow(S^1)^3\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow S_3\longrightarrow1.$$

Comment: @RobertBryant how to see that it's non-split?

Comment: @rori:  Since $\mathrm{Isom}(S^2,g)\simeq S^1$, one can write such isometries in the form $r_t:S^2\to S^2$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, where $r_t\circ r_s = r_{t+s}$.  The identity component of $\mathrm{Isom(X)}$ is then given by $r_{(t_1,t_2,t_3)} = r_{t_1} \times r_{t_2} \times r_{t_3}$.  If $G= S_3\times (S^1)^3$, let $\beta\in S^3\subset G$ be of the form $\beta(p_1,p_2,p_3) = \bigl(r_{s_2}(p_2),r_{s_3}(p_3),r_{s_1}(p_1)\bigr)$.  But $\beta$ would have to commute with all of the $r_{(t_1,t_2,t_3)}\in (S^1)^3$, which is clearly impossible (just write it out).

Comment: @RobertBryant thank you very much! Do I understand correctly that (a) the sequence would not split for two spheres as well (b) in your example, one could take the circle with round metric as a factor (if we pick an orientation and restrict to orientation-preserving isometries)?

Comment: @rori:  Yes, both those statements are correct.